# Android Auto-select check box

Tags: android, checkbox

Can some one tell me how can i auto select a check box when a function completes. I  check a condition, After the function has completed i need to automatically view that check box is selected.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share some of your code so we can understand your question? Or you can just try using myChkBox.setChecked(true) as last line of your function.

Comment: Something like findViewById().setChecked(true) should do its job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the CheckBox automatically from xml

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        .
.
.

        android:checked="true"
    />
```

or set java code like

```
CheckBox cbCheckbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
cbCheckbox .setChecked(true);
```